# Why my C code got error in Windows? Linux is ok

Tags: c, gcc

There is my C code, it is a [leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/add-binary/), and I got "Runtime Error". So I recompile in VS2013, the problem is `free(++tmp)`, why? I can't get it, I writen C code like that, just want to known more things about pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*   Add binary.
 *   a = "11", b = "1"
 *   result = "100"
 */

char *add_binary(char *a, char *b);

int main()
{
    printf("%s\n", add_binary("10", "1"));
    printf("%s\n", add_binary("1111", "1111"));
    return 0;
}

char *add_binary(char *a, char *b)
{
    int alen = 0, blen = 0, sum = 0;
    int len;
    char *tmp, *result;

    while(*a++) alen++;
    while(*b++) blen++;
    a -= 2;
    b -= 2;
    len = alen > blen ? alen : blen;
    tmp = (char *)malloc(len*sizeof(char));
    printf("%p\n", tmp);

    while(*a || *b){
        if(*a){
            sum += *a - '0' + 0;
            a--;
        }
        if(*b){
            sum += *b - '0' + 0;
            b--;
        }
        if(sum > 1){
            *tmp++ = 3 == sum ? '1' : '0';
            sum = 1;
        } else {
            *tmp++ = 1 == sum ? '1' : '0';
            sum = 0;
        }
    }
    *tmp = '\0';

    len += 1 == sum ? 1 : 0;
    result = (char *)malloc(len*sizeof(char));
    if(1 == sum){
        *result++ = '1';
    }
    while(*(--tmp)){
        *result++ = *tmp;
    }
    *result = '\0';
    printf("%p\n", tmp);
    free(++tmp);
    tmp = NULL;
    return (result-len);
}
```

Comment: runtime error is different to compile error - should change your title

Comment: I got the following error `memory clobbered before allocated block` which is not a compilation error...

Comment: If you pass two single-digit binary number strings to `add_binary()`, you are going to fail to allocate the space you request (because `len` will be `-1` and that translates to huge when converted to `size_t`).  Review your memory allocation policy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only pass to `free` the resulting pointer value of `malloc`:

```
tmp = (char *)malloc(len*sizeof(char));
```

then

```
free(tmp);
```

is OK.

But `free(++tmp)` or `free(tmp + 42)` is not OK and invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: `++tmp; free(tmp);`also got error, "Debug assertion failed".

Comment: Well, yes.  I just don't understand why you would increment a dynamic-allocated pointer and then try to free it?

Comment: Also '*tmp++' in the while block - also increments the pointer.

Comment: I can't got the point, `while(*(--tmp)){*result++ = *tmp;}` decrements the pointer.

Comment: @Damnever if you decrements the pointer, you change its value then you cannot pass it to `free` as it will not have the same value that was returned to `malloc`.

Comment: I suspect that the OP is claiming that the pointer gets put back to where it was originally.   Such a an approach to memory management is too complex for me - I would just keep a copy.

Comment: @MartinJames  Thank you also, I got it.

Answer (score 1):

Stop modifying the mallocated pointer before freeing it.  If you want to use pointer arithmetic, eg '*tmp++', then keep a copy of the original so that the space can be freed.

I have no clue why you would do 'free(++tmp);'.  It makes no sense though, by that time,  you've already totally shagged up tmp by incrementing it in the while loop:(

Edit: BTW, you've screwed 'result' as well.  You are returning a malloced and bodged pointer that cannot be correctly freed by the caller.

Whatever 'clever' thing you are attempting with the pointer manipulations, stop it. It's too easy to get it wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly more detailed response from the other answer.

The pointer is an address for which you allocate memory. When you pass in an address to free that has been previously malloc'd there is no problem. The problem is that you are not passing in the address of a malloc'd space. You are passing in the address of something that is potentially within a malloc'd space and as such cannot be freed.

Answer (score 0):

`free` expects its argument to be the *same pointer value* that was returned from a previous `malloc` or `realloc` call.  If you modify that pointer value before passing it to `free`, then the behavior is undefined and Bad Things can happen (this is why it appears to work for one platform and breaks on another; in truth, it's broken for both).

You'll need to preserve the pointer values returned from your `malloc` calls:

```
char *tmp, *tmpOrig;
...
tmp = tmpOrig = malloc(len * sizeof *tmpOrig); // note no cast, operand of sizeof
...
/**
 * modify tmp to your heart's desire
 */
...
free( tmpOrig );
```

You'll need to do the same thing for `result`.

You should not cast the result of `malloc`, unless you are working with a pre-C89 compiler.  It's unnecessary, and under C89/C90 compilers can mask a bug.